# _grokparsefailure while applying grok filters

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

My Log

```
2021-08-19 15:43:55,122 INFO c.t.i.c.ClassA - log message Service Name=Service-OCR Content ID=ABC.xml Category=SUCCESS Timestamp=2021-08-19T15:43:55.122292244 Message=The response has been received. Unit Name=N/A
2021-08-19 15:43:55,122 ERROR c.t.i.c.ClassB - log message Service Name=Service-OCR Engine Content ID=ABC.xml Category=ERROR Timestamp=2021-08-19T15:43:55.122292244 Message=The response has been received. Unit Name=TM
```

My `logstash.conf` is

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 12201
    codec => json_lines
  }
}


filter {
        grok {
                patterns_dir => ["./patterns"]
                match => {
                        'message' => '%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{STRING} - \"log message \"Service Name=\"%{STRING} \"Content ID=\"%{STRING} \"Category=\"%{STRING} \"Timestamp=\"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} \"Message=\"%{STRING} \"Unit Name=\"%{STRING}'
                }
        }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
    index => "logstash"
  }
}
```

I know that STRING is not in grok-filters that's why I have defined a customer filter.

```
STRING ^[a-zA-Z0-9 !@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]{1,}$
```

I am assuming that wherever I have used STRING that could include special characters ,spaces, numbers . Just like string in Java.

But still I am unable to filter my logs through this. Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

You have anchored STRING to the start and end of line using ^ and $. It is never going to match in the way you are using it. Remove the ^ and $

Comment: Kindly correct my grok filter and post in answer how I could fix it.

Comment: I have tried removing this . but no luck @Badger

Comment: Why do you escaped double quotes in your single quoted pattern when they do not appear in your log entries?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of custom patter STRING, you can simply use %{GREEDYDATA}. This will solve your problem.

Comment: %{GREEDYDATA} took all of the remaining log as string and ignore all other stuf..